# Manually Time Span

Tags: pseudocode, timespan

Given two inputs in date format that represents the start and the beggining of an event:

E.g.: `23:59` and `23:10`

How to manually calculate the time span, i mean the duration of this event?

You **could** considerate the interface:

`void timeSpan(int hourStart, int minutesStart, int hourEnd, int minutesEnd);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this really what you want?

```
endh,endm := split(':',endtime)
starth,startm := split(':',starttime)

diffm := endm-startm
diffh := endh-starth

if (diffm<0) 
  diffm += 60
  diffh -= 1
```

**Edit**

After discussion in the comments: If start time and end time are given only in HH:MM and end time < start time OQ wants us to assume, end time is next day (not +2 days, +3 days, ...). In this case we need:

```
if (diffh<0)
  diffh += 24
```

Comment: If `diffh <= 0` what happens? should I add it to 23?

Comment: If start and end are given in HH:MM this is not possible!

Comment: It is possible if the `end` represents the hour on the next day.

Comment: So you mean end=23:10, start=23:59? You should update your question to allow for that. Because we do not know, if it is 23:10 next day or +2 days or +3 days .... I updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

By "manually" I assume that you mean without a library to parse the times.

Convert the times to minutes, and subtract them:

```
start = "23:10"
end = "23:59"

s = parseInt(start.substr(0, 2)) * 60 + parseInt(start.substr(3, 2))
e = parseInt(end.substr(0, 2)) * 60 + parseInt(end.substr(3, 2))

diff = e - s
```

If the start date is after the end date, you get a negative result. If this means that the end time is the next daym you can add 24*60 minutes:

```
if diff < 0
  diff += 24*60
```

If it means that the times are just swapped, you can get the absolute value of the result:

```
diff = abs(diff)
```

Comment: @Richard: The time span in minutes.

Comment: if starting minutes are less than ending minutes the calc is right?

Comment: @Richard: If the start time is after the end time, then you get a negative result. If that means that the end time is the next day, you can add 24*60 minutes to the result to get the right result. If it means that the times are just swapped, you can get the absolute value of the result.